# List of mathematical notations - International convention

Tags: notation, education

I'm wondering if exist a list of mathematical notations accepted internationally (book, handbook, textbook etc.).
I tried to search online, but without success.

Comment: Different countries usually use . and , in incompatible ways, or use different trig function symbols, etc. So there's not an international standard for that sort of reason. Also, there's a lot of subfields of math so it would be very close to a list of all notation unless you had a field/specific bunch of symbols you were worried about.

Comment: such thing cannot exists for many reasons, the first is that it is unnecessary, and other reason could be that mathematics is a deeply creative thing, so each mathematician would like to use some notation over other, or create it personal notation, etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations.

Comment: Hello @JohnBentin, your answer here ( Looking for organisations promoting standard notation in mathemathics) is very useful.

Comment: @Masacroso, “each mathematician would like to use some notation over [an]other, or create it [as a mark of distinction as their] personal notation” that is the point:  a catalog/encyclopedia/database of all famous/key-contributor mathematician's notation that some other downstream mathematicians mimic (plus widely recognized international or national standards, but those are easier to find).